# Deleting row and then performing Select query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have to `delete` rows based on some condition and then i have select remaining rows using `Select` query, **will it be possible in SQL ?**.

both of this operation should goes with single query.

Please thought me, what is the primitive and best approach for this type of context.

Comment: something you have tried so far?

Comment: @Priyesh kumar, as it recommended by "Your Common Sense",i am performing delete query first and then select query on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** You `can't do it all in one query`, but you can do it all in one `TRANSACTION` if you are using a transactional store engine (like InnoDB). This might be what you want, but it's hard to tell only using the information you provided in your question.

#### Working on with TRANSACTION:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT STMT;
DELETE STMT;
UPDATE STMT;

COMMIT;
```

You can delete and select based on the below query based on the subquery with the help if `IN` operators and `WHERE`.

**IN Condition**

The MySQL IN condition is used to help reduce the need to use multiple OR conditions in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

**Note:**

1. The MySQL IN condition will return the records where expression is value1, value2..., or value_n.
2. The MySQL IN condition is also called the MySQL IN operator.

`DELETE from rooms WHERE initiating_user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_connected = 0)and target_user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_connected = 0)`

#### Working on with Procedure:

> You can create the procedure also for Doing this. Which will reduce the number of queries that you use in the Code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_update_delete(a)
BEGIN

UPDATE table_one SET table_one.avalue=1 WHERE table_one.another=a;

DELETE FROM table_two WHERE table_two.avalue=a;

SELECT * 
FROM table_one
WHERE table_one.another=a;

END;
```

Hope so my explanation will be clear for understanding your doubts..

Thanks & Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi Naresh, thanks for your answer. what i understood from above is that, it selects rows and then deletes it. eventually what is the resultant ? will i get remaining rows expect deleted one ?

Comment: Ya you can follow up the `procedure`  or `transaction` process

Comment: I noticed that your answers are good in general. However, you have to pay more attention to the question you answer. This answer is missing the OP by a mile.

Comment: @Your Common Sense. Ya after understanding the question a bit later i have suggested the `PROCEDURE` and `TRANSACTION` for further purpose operations

Comment: @YourCommonSense. Shall i remove the `IN` Statements or it shall be there so that it will be useful for the developer who has doubts..

Comment: @YourCommonSense. Since some might think `IN` Statements are irrelevant and i have already one negative vote for my answer.

Comment: The number of queries in the code is not a reason to do anything. Especially for making a code overcomplicated and hard to support.

Comment: That means i will keep the Procedure and Transaction alone since that alone will  be useful for all who has doubts

Comment: @YourCommonSense. I have updated the answer as per the advice given by you. Thanks for the advice and helping me how to pick up the errors that i have. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, here is the query what i am doing it now - SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT (scheduledDate <= timeBefore1Day AND state = "done").
now my requirement is to, delete rows permanently which holds good with this condition and then to fetch rows. this query is executing on sq-lite DB, so i don't have PROCEDURE or TRANSACTION

Comment: To whom you are talking? Nowhere did he say that your code works. Let alone all your suggestions has nothing to do with his question.

Answer (score 0):

> both of this operation should goes with single query.

It should not.

> Please thought me, what is the primitive and best approach for this type of context.

Just run two separate queries. Whatever your reason not to do so is wrong.

Comment: Hi, why do you recommend it as separate query ?

Comment: Because: you can't  do it in a single query; and there is not a single reason to do so.

Comment: Hi .. the thing is, i can't run this sequential one after the other, if i perform delete query first and then Select on two separate thread, it will not give guaranty which executes first. context here is to remove rows which is one day older than to show remaining row data on UI in mobile app

Comment: **WHAT?** "it will not give guaranty which executes first"? *Who said you that?*

Comment: Hi .. we have wrapper(A library) which takes care of executing queries on worker thread, doesn't impact main-thread from doing smooth navigation, animations and other stuffs . considering this, running query on separate thread for delete and select operation one after other may not produce expected result in my case.

Comment: You are confusing something. Your threads and animations has nothing to do with SQL **at all**. JUST RUN YOUR TWO QUERIES IN ORDER.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124625/discussion-between-chethan-and-your-common-sense).